# “Use case” vs “Test case” vs “Benchmark scenario”

Tags: system-software-testing

I am working on a European project proposal and I am writing the work package that deals with the validation of a software system for virtual reality. The tests will be done from a user's perspective and  using the software in a previously defined 3D scenario. Should I refer to that "test application" as a **Benchmark scenario**, a **Use case** or **Test case**?

The difference between them is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, it is **Use case.**

Brief description of all 3:

**Benchmark scenario:**  is the practice of a business comparing key metrics of their operations to other similar scenarios.

**Use Case:**  use case is a list of actions or event steps typically defining the interactions between a role (known in the Unified Modeling Language as an actor) and a system to achieve a goal. The actor can be a human or other external system.

**Test Case:** A test case is a set of conditions or variables under which a tester will determine whether a system under test satisfies requirements or works correctly.